# Modify class attributes in Eiffel

Tags: eiffel

Goodmorning.
I've starting using Eiffel at the University.

I have this example:

```
    class
      CLASS_1

    create make

    feature
      x: INTEGER

      make
        do
         x:=0
        end

      increment(inc: INTEGER)
        do
          x:=x+inc
        end

      get_x: INTEGER
        do
          Result:=x
        end
    end

----------------
class
   CLASS_2

create make_2

feature
    make_2
        do
            print("EXAMPLE")
            meth_1
        end
    meth_1
    local
        instance: CLASS_1
        i: INTEGER
    do
        create instance.make
        from
            i:=0
        until
            i<20
        loop
            instance.increment(5)
        end
        io.put_string ("The result is: ")
        io.put_integer (instance.get_x)
    end
end
```

Why the result is always 0? It seems like it doesn't update the value.
I've read that the client class attributes are read-only. Is it true?

Comment: Note: your feature `get_x`, is a function returning an integer. Therefore it should have a noun-phrase for a name, not a verb-phrase. Rational Eiffel coding standard and you don't say “What is the find_maximum value in the list?” or “Would you like get_fries with that?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with variable attributes, but with the fact that the loop is never executed. Just remove the loop while keeping the call to the procedure `increment` and you'll see the difference.

Talking about loops, the code has 2 issues:

1. Unlike the `while` loops in other languages, the expression in the `until` part is an exit condition. As soon as this condition is `true`, the loop exits. In this code this happens at the first iteration (because `i = 0` and `0 < 20`), i.e. without ever touching the loop body.
2. The variable `i` is not changed in the loop body and has the same initial value for all loop iterations.

Minor comments:

- There is no need for "getter" methods in Eiffel, such as `get_x`. You can use `x` directly.
- Self-initializing variable attributes are set to the default values on object creation. In particular, `x` is set to `0` when an object of type `CLASS_1` is created. Having `x := 0` in the creation procedure is harmless, but is also useless unless you want to use this procedure as a regular one as well.